# why httpHeader is been add as value

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-http-interceptors

I want to add a header to request but everything I tried does the same, it adds the name of myCustom header as a value to the header: `Access-Control-Request-Headers`,as I can see in the network chrome tools, so on the server side ( springboot) i m not able to read the value, only the name of my custom header.

Everything I do does the same, with interceptors or adding to a header in httpClient

```
return this.http.get(url,  
{
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('UserEmail', 'email' ) 
});
```

or interceptors

```
const tokenReq = req.clone({    
    headers: req.headers.set("authorization",  "zaraza")
});
return next.handle(tokenReq);
```

So userMail and authorization are value of a header like this:

Provisional headers are shown:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,useremail
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/users
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the preflight `OPTIONS` request, requested by CORS. You need to implement CORS on your API if you want to be able to use these headers

Comment: It is already implemented with: config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization", "authorization", "useremail"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));

Comment: You showed the headers for the `OPTIONS` request. What about the normal request that should come after?

Comment: Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/users
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127

Comment: That's still for the `OPTIONS` request I think. Edit your post to add the server response headers to that request

Comment: I m trying let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'useremail': 'myEmail '});   return this.http.get(url,  {headers: headers }); also the same thing, the response from server is ok with no errors, but still the custom header doesn't get attach @David it is not OPTIONS for sure